# Why is Javascript closure value apparently captured?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const history = useHistory();

  let [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      trackPageView();
      history.listen(trackPageView);
  }, []);

  function trackPageView() {
    console.log('hello: ' + val);
    setVal(val + 1);
  }
}
```

`useEffect` runs once and registers `trackPageView` with `history.listen`. As the history changes, `trackPageView` is called as expected but `val` always has the same start value of '0'. (The above code is based on the code in this [article](https://www.mparticle.com/blog/react-app-navigation-tracking).)

In contrast, this code does a similar thing...

```
var a = 1;

function g(f) {
    return () => f();
}

let func = g(() => console.log('a: ' + a));

func();

a = 2;

func();
```

...but `a`'s changing value is reflected in the output. https://jsfiddle.net/s3e250da/

So, what accounts for the difference in behaviour?

Comment: In Example 2 you change the value of `a`. Example 1 never changes `val`. `setVal` does not change local variables, it just asks react to rerender the component.

Comment: But isn't the local variable re-assigned by `useState` when the component is re-rendered?

Comment: No, assignment is only done via `=` like in second example. In react, no assignments happen, only re-declaration of variables. The `val` variable is re-declared each and every time it re-renders.

Comment: Each time `MyComponent` gets called (ie, rendered), it's going to make a new set of local variables. Those new variables may have new values, but there's no way for code in the previous render to access local variables from the next render. This is a brand new execution of `MyComponent`, with isolated variables.

Comment: You should’ve realized by now, in each re-render, that `val` is a freshly created brand new version of its previous self, like time traveling in multiverse, but they’re not the same variable. They are different variables that bear the same name.